# Compiling jar files results in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run a simple java program.

```
├── README.md
├── bin
│   └── myapp
│       └── myapp.class
├── build-jar
├── lib
│   ├── pdfbox-app-2.0.24.jar
├── manifest.txt
├── myapp.jar
└── src
    └── myapp
        └── myapp.java
```

So i then compiled my java class

```
javac -cp src/ src/myapp/*.java -d bin
javac -cp lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.24.jar src/myapp/*.java -d bin
jar -cvfm myapp.jar manifest.txt -C bin/ . src
```

however when i run my java file

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I got a exception saying my class is not found. However, I already included it when i did a javac. So Im a bit curious what went wrong? I am using VS code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

However, when i run the java class as it it works. My code as attached here

```
package myapp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;

public class myapp {

    public static String read_file(String fileName) throws IOException{
        String pdfFileInText ="";
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName))) {

            document.getClass();

            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
            
                PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
                stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

                PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

                pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                //System.out.println("Text:" + st);

                // split by whitespace
                String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    //System.out.println(line);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        return pdfFileInText;
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String return_text = read_file("xxx.pdf");
        System.out.println(return_text);
        System.out.println("Hello, Test!");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the library when compiling. Usually the code editor or IDE does that automatically. I'm not quire sure why you're compiling twice to be honest. But from the terminal/cmd you'll have to include it manually as so:

```
javac -cp ".:path/to/lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.24.jar;" myapp.java
```

SN: Just to point out that Java conventions usually require CamelCase class names.

Comment: I did. javac -cp "/xxxxx/github/java/lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.24.jar;" src/myapp/*.java -d bin

Got src/myapp/myapp.java:4: error: package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel does not exist

Comment: is /xxxxx/ the absolute first folder for that path? also do not forget the .:

Comment: Yes i did .:/Users/john/Documents/github/sampleproject/lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.24.jar;